# Explain running time on this python TREE algorithm for finding heights

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures, tree

Here below I have attached a block of code. You guys please tell how the following code has **O(n)** time running time.

```
def _height2(self, p):
     if self.is_leaf(p):
          return 0
     else:
          return 1 + max(self._height2(c) for c in self.children(p))
```

I can't understand how it works in **O(n)** time complexity.
Please help me to learn that.

Comment: it would be order n if there were some memoization involved.

Comment: Bro we try accessing each node once and in worst case we try accessing height from Root node and so we get O(n) time complexity for n number of nodes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that *n* represents the number of nodes in the tree, we can observe the following:

`c in self.children(p)` will never produce the same *c* twice: all nodes, except the root, will at some point be that *c*, and only once. And so this code represents a constant time complexity *per node*. Moreover, `_height2` will be called for all nodes exactly once. For the root this is the initial call, and for all other nodes it is a recursive call.

All other code (apart from the iteration over the children and the recursive call) represents a constant time complexity *per node*.

So we have a *O(n)* time complexity.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir I understood the concept behind this.